# Closing a JFrame when double clicked on icon

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to ask you that when I double click on the icon on `JFrame` I just added with `setIconImage()` method it is closing the frame.

Is it possible to lock it and only to exit from the button `X`?

Comment: Short answer, no, these kind of things are generally controlled by the OS. Long answer, if you "really" (really) want this functionality, you will have to provide your own frame decorations

Answer (score 1):

you can use following coding snippet to block default close operation.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

and in you button X actionListener you can use following code

```
frame.dispose()
```

Sample code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] str) { 

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton but = new JButton("X");
        panel.add(but);

        but.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();

            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(100,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```